# Is there a way to get nunit-console to indicate its progress?

Tags: nunit, nunit-console

nunit-console doesn't give a progress indicator at the command line indicating tests that have passed or failed until all tests have run.  This kinda sucks since rspec will output each passing/failing test.

Is there a way to make nunit-console indicate a passing/failing test *as it's running*?

If it matters, I'm passing multiple assemblies into a single command line call to nunit-console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll find some code [here](http://imistaken.blogspot.com/2009/03/nunit-extensions-adding-logic-at-run.html) to create an addin dll to NUnit (the instructions are simple). You could use TestStarted() and TestFinished() to write on the console that a test have started or finished, failed or succeeded.